# Melhor maneira de configurar o content-length do cabeçalho HTTP

Tags: java, servlet, vídeo, http-headers, html5-video

Olá,

Eu tenho um player de vídeo que faz uma requisição via Servlet que já funciona e preciso incluir um novo vídeo.

A principio vou retornar o vídeo de acordo com o usuário logado.

O problema que eu me deparei é que os vídeos são de tamanhos diferentes e o response header possui uma configuração de Content-Length pré definida que acredito ser do vídeo que já exista:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Length", "15800000");
```

Eu pesquisei sobre as propriedades de cabeçalho e não entendi se é válido omitir esse valor ou tentar programar de alguma forma a alteração desse cabeçalho de resposta.

Esse é o Servlet:

```
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(FileServerUtil.getFileServer()
            + PASTA_MEDIA + File.separator + NOME_ARQUIVO);
         ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
        response.setContentType("video/mp4");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("accept-ranges", "bytes");
        response.setHeader("cache-control", "public,max-age=14400,public");
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", "15800000");

        byte [] buf = new byte[4096];
        int read;
        while((read = fin.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
}
```

Eu poderia colocar um if else e alterar o cabeçalho de acordo com o vídeo mas acredito que seria uma forma "burra" de fazer. Gostaria de uma sugestão sobre isso!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Acabei alterando o meu `FileInputStream` para `RandomAccessFile`, assim puder utilizar o método 
`length()`, não sei se seria uma boa abordagem mas agora consigo obter o tamanho do arquivo em bytes para incluir no cabeçalho.